# Making a list of streetadresses

Tags: python, fme

SOLVED :-)
I'm having this list, and would like to get the expected result, but no luck.
Tried in python and FME

If there is more than 2 between the current and then previous number, a new line has to start

Can anybody help? Preferable in FME, but okay in python too

```
StreetName;HouseNumber;OddEven
Northroad;1;O
Northroad;2;E
Northroad;3;O
Northroad;4;E
Northroad;8;E
Northroad;10;E
Southroad;1;O
Southroad;2;E
Southroad;3;O
Southroad;4;E
Southroad;10;E
Southroad;12;E
Southroad;14;E
```

My result:

```
Northroad 1-3
Northroad 2-10
Southroad 1-3
Southroad 2-14
```

Expected result:

```
Northroad 1-3
Northroad 2-4
Northroad 8-10
Southroad 1-3
Southroad 2-4
Southroad 10-14
```

Does it make any sense?

Comment: Are you sure that the list is sorted on input?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly does not work? Please give us more details about the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a medium complexity parsing, processing and formatting task, so I would use classes: one for a contiguous address range on one side of one road, and one to be the container of that ranges. That way the load interface will be as simple as adding a decoded row, and the formatting interface will be as simple.

Code could be:

```
# set the filenames here:
filename = "input.csv"
out = output.txt
class AddressRange:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.road = row[0]
        self.low = self.high = int(row[1])
        self.side = row[2]

    def add(self, row):
        if (self.road != row[0]) or (self.side != row[2]):
            return False
        val = int(row[1])
        if val < self.low <= val+2:
            self.low = val
        elif val-2 <= self.high < val:
            self.high = val
        else:
            return False
        return True
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %d-%d' % (self.road, self.low, self.high)

class AddressList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ranges = []
    def add(self, row):
        for ar in self.ranges:
            if ar.add(row):
                break
        else:
            self.ranges.append(AddressRange(row))
    def print(self, fd=sys.stdout):
        for ar in self.ranges:
            print(str(ar), file=fd)


with open(filename) as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter = ';')
    lst = AddressList()
    _ = next(fd)              # skip header line
    for row in rd:
        if len(row) == 3:
            lst.add(row)

with open(out, 'w') as fd:
    lst.print(out)
```

With the sample input file, the ouput is as expected:

```
Northroad 1-3
Northroad 2-4
Northroad 8-10
Southroad 1-3
Southroad 2-4
Southroad 10-14
```